# Media queries not working despite simple use

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I have a very simple media query. However, it is not working. Here's the code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport" />

  <style>
    #landscape-div {
      display: none;
    }

    @media (min-width: 800px) {
      #landscape-div {
        display: block;
      }
    }
    
  
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="landscape-div">fsfsfsfsfsdd</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Expected result: the `div` should show up only when the minimum width is more than 800px.

However, it is showing up all the time. Why is this happening?

Edit: Edited the code as suggested by answers. Still not working.

Comment: For one thing your HTML is using an ID and you style is using a *class*. Also the order of the styles is important. Try putting the media query after the original style.

Comment: `display: none` will **ALWAYS** fire, because it's not qualified, so whatever media query is applied is immediately overwritten.

Comment: @Martin what is a fix then? i have definitely used this before.

Comment: @RayNorman My answer below fixes that exact problem. Sorry it was vague to begin with, but I have now edited it and it is working perfectly. (View code snippet in full page by pressing 'expand snippet' to try it out)

Comment: If you write your query as @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) with display: none; The display: none will fire as ray might expect, however, it has to be written that way. xD

Comment: I voted this down because there are mistakes in your document, and furthermore, they are not even related to the question you asked. Make sure each part of your code is functioning except for the part you are asking about. Not doing this is like asking someone to write code for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your media query has been overridden. The best practice is to write media queries at the end of all styles

Update your styles like below:

```css
#landscape-div {
  display: none;
}

@media (min-width: 800px) {
  #landscape-div {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are referring to an `id` using a `.` in your CSS. However, this will only work for classes. To refer to an `id`, you need to use the `#` symbol instead.

> Edit: this was a typo in the original question and has now been fixed.

The media query will have to come first to make sure the other statement does not override it, because statements that come later in a CSS document will be chosen as most relevant by the browser.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport" />

  <style>

    #landscape-div {
      display: none;
    }

    @media (min-width: 800px) {
      #landscape-div {
        display: block;
      }
    }
    
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="landscape-div">fsfsfsfsfsdd</div>
</body>

</html>
```

View the code snippet above in full screen (by clicking 'expand snippet') to see that it is working.

Comment: This still needs a bit of fixing. The media query needs to come after the initial `display: none` rule in order for this to work because... CSS cascades. See Paulie_D's comment on the question above.

Comment: That was a mistake while typing. It is still not working.

Comment: @volt Can you please explain a little? The media query is put after the display:none

Comment: @Run_Script "Note that the div never appears at all in the code snippet above, because the width always stays under 800px." - I did not understand. It is actually showing up in all screens. Also, the div should be visible if I open it from any screen with size above 800px, right?

Comment: @RayNorman the answer was edited after my comment. It should work now once you click on the Full page link in the snippet above. +1 for fixing it Run_Script

Comment: @volt Thanks for the help editing this answer! It should all be working now.